# cant create google api key for my ios bundle id

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

Im integrating Google Places Api for my iOS app. My app's bundle id is as follows "com.MyCompany.Txi.iOSClient". When i trying to get a api key from google developer site it's not allow me to create. I think reason is this bundle id name. How can i overcome this issue. I can't change bundle id because it's my comapny's request.

Comment: please paste error msg here

Comment: issue is fixed. what i did was just go to google  developer console and i create a my project with bundle id then i was able to get a key for that.